# Convexity of an awful function involving a quotient of gamma functions and expected value

Tags: stochastic-processes, convex-analysis

I have a function, lets call it $f$

$$
f(a,b) = e^{-ak} \frac{\Gamma(-a) \Gamma (-b)}{\Gamma{(-a-b+2)}} \cdot \\ \mathbb{E} \left[ e^{A(\tau) -aX_1 - bX_2 + B_1(\tau)V_1 + B_2(\tau)V_2 + B_m(\tau) V_m}| (X_1(0), X_2(0), V_1(0), V_2(0), V_m(0)) = (x_1, x_2, v_1, v_2, v_m)\right]
$$
where $a<0$ and $b<0$, and conditioned on start values. My main wish is to prove that $f$ is convex. 
**Edit**

$\textit{Added information about the stochastic variables}$

The $X_i, V_i$ are stochastic processes, where $X_i$ is thought to be the $\log$ of a stock, and $V_i$ are volatilites.

\begin{align}
dX_1 = & \ \left(r- \frac{V_1}{2} - V_m \frac{\sigma_{1m}^2}{2}\right) dt + \left( \sqrt{V_1} dW_{11} + \sigma _{1m} \sqrt{V_m} dW_{12} \right) \nonumber \\
dX_2 = & \ \left(r- \frac{V_2}{2} - V_m \frac{\sigma_{2m}^2}{2}\right) dt +  \left( \sqrt{V_2} dW_{21} + \sigma _{2m} \sqrt{V_m} dW_{22} \right) \nonumber \\
dV_1 = & \ \kappa _1 (\theta _1 - V_1) dt + \sqrt{V_1} \sigma _1 dW_{V_1} \label{eq:21} \\
dV_2 = & \ \kappa _2 (\theta _2 - V_2) dt + \sqrt{V_2} \sigma _2 dW_{V_2} \nonumber \\
dV_m = & \ \kappa _m (\theta _m - V_m) dt + \sqrt{V_m} \sigma _m dW_{V_m}. \nonumber
\end{align}

**-**

We have 
$$
 B_1(\tau) =
     \left(\frac{\rho_{11} \sigma_1 a + \kappa_1}{\sigma_1^2}\right) + \\ 
    \sqrt{\frac{a(a+1)}{\sigma_1^2} - 
    \left(\frac{\rho_{11}\sigma_1 a + \kappa_1}{\sigma_1 ^2}\right)^2} \cdot 
    \tan \left( \sqrt{\left(\sigma_1 ^2 a(a+1) - (\rho_{11} \sigma_1 a + \kappa_1)^2 \right)} \left(\frac{\tau + C_1}{2}\right) \right)
$$
and
$$
C_1 = \frac{2\arctan \left(\frac{-\rho_{11} \sigma_1 a - \kappa_1}{\sqrt{-\sigma_1^2 a(-a-1) - 
    \left(-\rho_{11}\sigma_1 a - \kappa_1\right)^2}}\right)}
    { \sqrt{\left( -\sigma_1 ^2a (-a-1) - (-\rho_{11} \sigma_1 a - \kappa_1)^2 \right)}}
$$
and
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{gathered}
   B_2 (\tau) =
    - \frac{-\rho_{22} \sigma_2 b - \kappa_2}{\sigma_2^2} + \\ 
    \sqrt{\frac{-b(-b-1)}{\sigma_2^2} - 
    \left(\frac{-\rho_{22}\sigma_2 b - \kappa_2}{\sigma_2 ^2}\right)^2} \cdot 
    \tan \left( \sqrt{\left(- \sigma_2 ^2 b(-b-1) - (-\rho_{22} \sigma_2 b - \kappa_2)^2 \right)} \left(\frac{\tau + C_2}{2}\right) \right) \\
\text{and}\\
     C_2 = \frac{2\arctan \left(\frac{-\rho_{22} \sigma_2 b - \kappa_2}{\sqrt{-\sigma_2^2b(-b-1) - 
    \left(-\rho_{22}\sigma_2 b - \kappa_2\right)^2}}\right)}
    { \sqrt{\left(- \sigma_2 ^2 b(-b-1) - (-\rho_{22} \sigma_2 b - \kappa_2)^2 \right)}}
    \end{gathered}
\end{equation*}
Followed by
\begin{equation*}
\begin{gathered}
B_m = 
     - \frac{-a \sigma_{1m} \sigma_{m} \rho_{1m} - b \sigma_{2m} \sigma_{m} \rho_{2m} - \kappa_m}{\sigma_m^2} + \\
     \sqrt{\frac{\sigma_{1m}^2(a^2 + a) + \sigma_{2m}^2(b^2 + b) + \sigma_{1m} \sigma_{2m} \rho_{12m} ab}{\sigma_m^2} - \left( \frac{-a \sigma_{1m} \sigma_{m}\rho_{1m} - b \sigma_{2m} \sigma_{m} \rho_{2m} - \kappa_m}{\sigma_m^2} \right)^2} \\
     \cdot \\
     \tan \Bigg( \sqrt{\sigma_m^2( \sigma_{1m}^2a^2 + a) + \sigma_{2m}^2 (b^2 + b) + \sigma_{1m} \sigma_{2m} \rho_{12m} ab ) - (-a \sigma_{1m} \sigma_m \rho_{1m} - b \sigma_{2m} \sigma_m \rho_{2m} - \kappa_m)^2} \\   \left( \frac{\tau + C_m}{2} \right)\Bigg) 
\end{gathered}
\end{equation*}
With
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{gathered}
    C_m = \frac{2 \arctan \left(\frac{-a \sigma_{1m} \sigma_{m} \rho_{1m} - b \sigma_{2m} \sigma_{m} \rho_{2m} - \kappa_m}{\sigma_m^2} \right) }{\sqrt{\sigma_m^2( \sigma_{1m}^2(a^2 + a) + \sigma_{2m}^2 (b^2 + b) + \sigma_{1m} \sigma_{2m} \rho_{12m} ab ) - (-a \sigma_{1m} \sigma_m \rho_{1m} - a \sigma_{2m} \sigma_m \rho_{2m} - \kappa_m)^2}}
    \end{gathered}
\end{equation*}
And then the most awful one
\begin{equation*}
\begin{gathered}
A(\tau) = C_A - \tau r (a + b) + \int \kappa_1 \theta_1 B_1(\tau) + \kappa_2 \theta_2 B_2 (\tau) + \kappa _m \theta_m B_m (\tau) d\tau
    \end{gathered}
\end{equation*}
Where
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{gathered}
    C_A = \\
    \kappa_1 \theta_1 \frac{c_{2,1} \log \left(\cos(c_{3,1} C_1)\right)}{c_{3,1}} + 
    \kappa_2 \theta_2 \frac{c_{2,2} \log \left(\cos(c_{3,2} C_2)\right)}{c_{3,2}} + 
    \kappa_m \theta_m \frac{c_{2,m} \log \left(\cos(c_{3,m} C_m)\right)}{c_{3,m}}  \\
    \end{gathered}
\end{equation*}
With
\begin{align*}
-&c_{1,1} = - \frac{-\rho_{11} \sigma_1 a - \kappa_1}{\sigma_1^2} & 
-&c_{1,2} =  - \frac{-\rho_{22} \sigma_2 b - \kappa_2}{\sigma_2^2}&  \\
&c_{2,1} = \sqrt{\frac{-a(-a-1)}{\sigma_1^2} - \left(\frac{-\rho_{11}\sigma_1 a - \kappa_1}{\sigma_1 ^2}\right)^2}& 
&c_{2,2} = \sqrt{\frac{-b(-b-1)}{\sigma_2^2} - \left(\frac{-\rho_{22}\sigma_2 b - \kappa_2}{\sigma_2 ^2}\right)^2}& \\
&c_{3,1} = \sqrt{\left(- \sigma_1 ^2 a(-a-1) - (-\rho_{11} \sigma_1 a - \kappa_1)^2 \right)}&
&c_{3,2} = \sqrt{\left(-b \sigma_2 ^2 b(-b-1) - (-\rho_{22} \sigma_2 b - \kappa_2)^2 \right)}&
\end{align*}

and

\begin{equation*}
\begin{gathered}
    -c_{1,m} = - \frac{-a \sigma_{1m} \sigma_{m} \rho_{1m} - b \sigma_{2m} \sigma_{m} \rho_{2m} - \kappa_m}{\sigma_m^2} \\
    c_{2,m} =  \sqrt{\frac{\sigma_{1m}^2(a^2 + a) + \sigma_{2m}^2(b^2 + b) + \sigma_{1m} \sigma_{2m} \rho_{12m} ab}{\sigma_m^2} - \left( \frac{-a \sigma_{1m} \sigma_{m}\rho_{1m} - b \sigma_{2m} \sigma_{m} \rho_{2m} - \kappa_m}{\sigma_m^2} \right)^2} \\
    c_{3,m} = \sqrt{\sigma_m^2( \sigma_{1m}^2(a^2 + a) + \sigma_{2m}^2 (b^2 + b) + \sigma_{1m} \sigma_{2m} \rho_{12m} ab ) - (-a \sigma_{1m} \sigma_m \rho_{1m} - b \sigma_{2m} \sigma_m \rho_{2m} - \kappa_m)^2} 
    \end{gathered}
\end{equation*}

I dont even know where to start and attack this problem. Any suggestion or strategy for getting started is appreciated.

**Update**
The $\rho$:s are correlations so they are between $-1$ and $1$. Other constants e.g. $\sigma$ $\kappa$ can be assumed to $>0$. By correspondance with my professor he is under the impression that the $B_i$s themself doesnt need to be convex, but since the $V_i$:s can be arbitrarily close to $0$ $A$ must be convex.

Comment: You have my sympathies. Why not change the sign of a and b so they are > 0?

Comment: Hehe thanks! Because of convention, from the original context from where this problem arise. @martycohen

Comment: Basically it's from a Fourier transformation in $z_1 = -a - w_1$ and $z_2 = -b - w_2$ and those are well-defined whenever $\Re(z_1), \Re(z_2) < 0$. Convention being, "Have same sign on the constant making the transform exist, and the variable in which the transform is performed". @martycohen

Comment: what is the relation between $X$ and $X(0)$? Is the fourier transform the integral of a convex function?

Comment: @LinAlg X is an assets modelled by the heston modell and V is volatility. X(0) is the start value of the asset, V(0) is the start value of the volatility. The function which transforms to the above f, is convex yes

Comment: I would create a plot at this point to produce visual evidence.

Comment: I could, but problem is, function involves $\tan$ which in theory shouldnt create any spikes, but numerically matlab doesnt handle that do well. @LinAlg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not only convex, but even logarithmically convex.

We can write, denoting $x = -a$, $y=-b$, $g(x,y) = f(-x,-y)$ that
$$
g(x,y) = e^{kx} \frac{\mathrm{B}(x+1,y+1)}{xy}\mathbb{E}^* \left[e^{xX_1+yX_2}\right],
$$
where $\mathrm{B}$ is the beta function,
$$
\frac{d\mathbb P^*}{d\mathbb P} = e^{A(\tau) + B_1(\tau)V_1 + B_2(\tau)V_2 + B_m(\tau) V_m}.
$$

Then 
$$
\log g(x,y) = \log \mathrm{B}(x+1,y+1) + kx -\log x - \log y + \log \mathbb{E}^* \left[e^{xX_1+yX_2}\right].
$$
The beta function is log-convex (see e.g. Theorem 6 [here](http://rgmia.org/papers/v2n3/begaostr.pdf)), $kx-\log x$ and $-\log y$ are convex, and $\log \mathbb{E}^* \left[e^{xX_1+yX_2}\right]$ is the cumulant generating function for $(X_1,X_2)$, so also convex. Hence the claim.

Comment: Expectation with respect to the $\mathbb{P^*/P}$ measure? Or how do you define it?

Comment: @Olba12, the star expectation is with respect to $\mathbb P^*$ i.e. $\mathbb E^* [X] = \int_{\Omega} X(\omega) d\mathbb{P}^*(\omega)$.